# The explicit keyword and constructors with more than one parameter for C++11

Tags: c++11, explicit

In general, I've heard it's good practice to use the explicit keyword on constructors with a single argument. However, as of C++11, constructors with more than one argument can be used for implicit conversions. As such, is it good practice to apply the explicit keyword to ALL constructors of > 0 arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for explicit is, do you want this constructor to be called implicitly?

If yes, don't make it explicit.

If no, make it explicit.

For 1 argument ctors, if converting from that type is as lossless and innocuous as converting an `int` to a `double` when needed, make it implicit.

For >1 argument ctors, determine if you want `{}` based construction to work.  Sometimes it is a good idea, sometimes a bad idea.

In C++11 and 14, `{}` construction is needed in order to return a value from a function when the type cannot be moved or copied.  In some cases, you'll use a tag type to make `{}` more explicit than it otherwise would be if you want to avoid "implicit `{}` usage" for whatever reason.

In C++17, there are fewer reasons to really need `{}` because prvalues are no longer objects but rather construction instructions; that means `return T(blah)` doesn't move/copy the `T` in a function returning `T`, but rather direction constructs it from `blah`.

When exactly you want to block `{}` is a matter of opinion, and not suitable for a SO Q&A.